# Не могу добавить QActionGroup в QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня возникла проблема с добавлением QActionGroup в QMenu. Экшны меню выглядят так, словно я добавил обычные QAction, а не QActionGroup. В чем может быть причина? Вроде все сделал как в примере из доков.

```
    QAction *colorRed = new QAction(tr("Red"), this);
    QAction *colorblue = new QAction(tr("Blue"), this);
    QAction *colorPink = new QAction(tr("Pink"), this);
    QActionGroup *fontColorActionGroup = new QActionGroup(this);
    fontColorActionGroup->addAction(colorRed);
    fontColorActionGroup->addAction(colorblue);
    fontColorActionGroup->addAction(colorPink);
    fontColorActionGroup->actions().at(0)->setChecked(true);
    fontColorActionGroup->setExclusive(true);
    ui->menuSettings->addActions(fontColorActionGroup->actions());
```

Comment: Qt 5.12.1 Winddows 7 x64. У меня ваш код работает. Что-то видимо с menuSettings

Comment: Qt 5.12.1 Linux Mint 19.1 x64 Cinnamon - Меню отобразилось корректно только после того, как я проставил setCheckable(true); всем QAction. В доках про необходимость этого вроде бы ни слова, как и в примере оттуда. Ну, главное, что заработало.